# Quartz trigger disappears from database

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I have quartz schedule that randomly deleted from our database.
The schedule is expected to run twice a day but one day it did not run and the trigger was deleted in the database.

I've tried researching on what could cause this. One possible cause was the trigger didn't have NEXTFIRE_TIME so quartz deleted the trigger but all our triggers does not have END_TIME set in the database.

What could cause the deletion of the triggers in the database?
We are using quartz-2.2.1.jar.

Answer (score 0):

There is any code like Scheduler.deleteJob()?

This function not only clears job but also clears trigger.

Would you check that function in your code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sjtS.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).